# IE7 and dropdown list - adds margin of some kind

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7

I have a dropdown menu I created and IE7 has decided to create some margin between each list item on the dropdown selections even though the list items have no margin or padding.

You can see it here: http://www.condorstudios.com/stuff/temp/index.php

Comment: I wonder if you can merge all your past few questions into one: "help me get this page working" :)

Comment: lol yeah, this page has been a pain in the you know what lol.... but pretty much all IE stuff as per usual :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this pretty quickly by setting the background color of the parent div to the same as the background color of the  list items. You'll always find quirks with Internet Explorer and margins, padding, widths, etc.

This CSS should also work (IE pads all list items), but I'd test this first to see how it changes the layout on other browsers.

```
li {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Depending on how 'hacky' you want to get, there are ways of including CSS that only IE-6,7,8 will interpret: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/  Scroll down to the  'Hacks' section.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simple solution and yep, I hate getting things to work with IE ;)

Comment: No problem, I have to work with old Internet Explorer versions all the time. Huge pain!

Comment: Yep, already tried that margin trick and already use a reset.css file to reset everything but IE7 didn't change. Background color worked like a treat though! :)